# Comparing string input

Tags: java

I'm not sure why `guess` isn't the same as `words[random][0]` even if I type the correct answer. It skips the if statment and goes to `else`.

```
    do{

System.out.println("The scrambled word is: " + scramble[random]);

                Scanner fooBar = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("What is this word?: ");
                guess = fooBar.next();

                if(guess == words[random][0])
                {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, you have guessed correctly!");
                    done = true;
                }
            else
                System.out.println("Sorry, that is not it.");

            }while(done == false);
```

Comment: use `equals()` <!----->

Comment: We need to get these on auto-close :P

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thank you. 
I'm new to Java, coming from C++. So I'm used to using the `==` operator.

Comment: @Reimeus duplicate of  - auto suggest or a short id to enter or something like that would be cool